# Getting a value by ID saving it to a variable and then printing the variable

Tags: jquery

So I am just trying to save a value from a div to a variable and then print it.

Here is what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/akpn3/449/

```
<script text/type="javascript">
var string = $('.label_text_price_overview').val();
$('.listprice').html(string);
</script>
<span class="label_text_price_overview"><span class="nobreak">USD <span>279.00</span></span></span>
<p class="listprice"></p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spans don't have a value, use `.text()` (or `.html()` if you also want the inner spans) instead:

```
var string = $('.label_text_price_overview').text();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/akpn3/450/)**

Comment: I am trying to look it up right now but what if I just need to number and not USD.

Comment: You could change the selector to `var string = $('.label_text_price_overview span span').text();`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7eSZj/. There's a few ways to do this in jQuery. If you want to do any math with it, you can use parseFloat() or parseInt() as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

1. `text/type` is not a valid HTML attribute.  You can just do `<script>`.
2. `.label_text_price_overview` is a `<span>`.  Those do not have values.  You probably want `.text()`.
3. You need to run your JavaScript once the DOM is ready, so wrap it in `$(function(){})`.  This waits until the document is ready.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var string = $('.label_text_price_overview').text();
    $('.listprice').html(string);
});
</script>
<span class="label_text_price_overview"><span class="nobreak">USD <span>279.00</span></span></span>
<p class="listprice"></p>
```

Comment: In the fiddle, OP has the script running onload

Comment: @Huangism: I didn't check the demo link, but my guess is that he only has it running onload because that's jsFiddle's default option.  I'm not sure if he has it onload in his *real* code, so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Well Thank you for mentioning it